# Can I call a named scope from within the model code where it was just defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is my model and I'm trying to call `self.red` but it's not working. Is this even possible?

```
# Shirt has size and color
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
    scope :red, where(:color => 'red')

    def find_red
        return self.red
    end
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try `Shirt.red`
`self.red` would be an object method.  `scope :red` is already a class method so you don't have to write a method `find_red` to perform a query, `Shirt.red` will already do that.

Answer (score 2):

You might find calling `self.class.red` preferable to the `Shirt.red` proposed in the other answers. It isn't quite as nice to read, but it has the advantage that if the classes name every changes your code can remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a instance method by doing return self.red.

What you want to achieve is

```
def find_red
    return Shirt.red
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thought I'd throw this out there related to this thread in case someone stumbles upon it.

You should stay away from calling scopes from within instance methods. You'll quickly find yourself debugging performance issues. Scopes will ALWAYS go back to the database regardless if a relationship is included.

I.e.

```
class Show
  has_many :episodes

  def awesome_episodes
    episodes.awesome # THIS IS BAD!!
    # should stay in ruby land with episodes.select { |ep| ep.status == "awesome" } 
    # OR push a method #awesome? to the episode class and then the 
    # syntax becomes nicer: episodes.select(&:awesome?)
    # This way, the onus is on the caller to include the relationship 
  end
end

class Episode
  belongs_to :show

  scope :awesome, ()-> { where(status: 'awesome') }
end

shows = Show.includes(:episodes)

shows.map do |show|
  show.awesome_episodes # fires a query every loop
end
```